# pdflatex.exe: the memory dump file could not be found / Miktex does not build formats

Tags: errors, miktex, format-files

Im using Windows 10 pro, and I installed both MikTeX (basic-miktex-22.3-x64) and Texmaker (Texmaker_5.1.3_Win_x64). When I try to build any .tex file in Texmaker it gives me the error:

> pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

> Process started Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\YesabethGB\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
> Process exited with error(s)

The log says this:

```
2022-05-30 12:41:18,200-0400 INFO  pdflatex - this process (11140) started by texmaker in directory C:\Users\YesabethGB\Desktop\texm\partes with command line: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode prueba.tex2022-05-30 12:41:18,207-0400 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.10.0 (1.40.24) (MiKTeX 22.3)
2022-05-30 12:41:18,213-0400 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-05-30 12:41:18,286-0400 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2022-05-30 12:41:18,286-0400 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: miktex formats build pdflatex --engine pdftex
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 ERROR pdflatex - C:\Users\YesabethGB\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 ERROR pdflatex - output:
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 ERROR pdflatex - Building format 'pdflatex' with engine 'pdftex'...

Sorry, but: The executed process did not succeed.

2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:697
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 697
2022-05-30 12:41:20,278-0400 INFO  pdflatex - this process (11140) finishes with exit code 1
```

When I searched for a solution most of what I read said that it was an installation related problem in which the formats were not build and the solution for most people was to reinstall MikTeX. So I uninstalled both MikTeX and Texmaker using IObit Uninstaller, then I rebooted the PC and reinstalled both programs, same thing happened.

Then I tried to build them manually in the MikTeX console (all of the formats appeared either blank or excluded in the attributes section of the menu), then this error appeared:

> One MiKTeX Utility failed for some reason. The output has been saved to a file.

I looked into the makefmt folder and there was this log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) (INITEX)  30 MAY 2022 13:42
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled. (cp227.tcx)
**C:/Users/YesabethGB/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex
.ini

(C:/Users/YesabethGB/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/tex/latex/00miktex/pdflatex.
ini
(C:\Users\YesabethGB\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/config\pdftexconfig.tex
)
(C:\Users\YesabethGB\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\latex.ltx
(C:\Users\YesabethGB\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\texsys.cfg)
\openout15 = `texsys.aux'.


./texsys.aux found


\@currdir set to: ./.


Assuming \openin and \input 
have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers,
\@inputcheck=\read0
\@unused=\write0
\maxdimen=\dimen10
\hideskip=\skip10
\p@=\dimen11
\z@=\dimen12
\z@skip=\skip11
\voidb@x=\box10
 parameters,
\normalbaselineskip=\skip12
\normallineskip=\skip13
\normallineskiplimit=\dimen13
\interfootnotelinepenalty=\count23
\strutbox=\box11

LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1

(C:\Users\YesabethGB\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.ltx

(C:\Users\YesabethGB\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-cod
e.tex
Package: expl3 2022-05-04 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count24
\l_tmpa_int=\count25
\l_tmpb_int=\count26
\g_tmpa_int=\count27
\g_tmpb_int=\count28
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count29
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count30
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count31
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count32
\c_log_iow=\count33
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count34
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count35
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count36
\l__iow_indent_int=\count37
\c_zero_dim=\dimen14
\c_max_dim=\dimen15
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen16
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen17
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen18
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen19
\c_zero_skip=\skip14
\c_max_skip=\skip15
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip16
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip17
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip18
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip19
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count38
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count39
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen20
\g__intarray_font_int=\count40
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count41
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count42
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count43
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count44
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count45
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count46
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count47
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count48
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count49
\c__kernel_randint_max_int=\count50
\g__fp_array_int=\count51
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count52
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count53
\l__sort_length_int=\count54
\l__sort_min_int=\count55
\l__sort_top_int=\count56
\l__sort_max_int=\count57
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count58
\l__sort_block_int=\count59
\l__sort_begin_int=\count60
\l__sort_end_int=\count61
\l__sort_A_int=\count62
\l__sort_B_int=\count63
\l__sort_C_int=\count64
\c__str_replacement_char_int=\count65
\l__str_modulo_int=\count66
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count67
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count68
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count69
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count70
\l__tl_peek_charcode_int=\count71
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count72
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count73
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count74
\l__regex_balance_int=\count75
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count76
\l__regex_mode_int=\count77
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count78
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count79
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count80
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count81
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count82
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count83
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count84
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count85
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count86
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count87
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count88
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count89
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count90
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count91
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count92
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count93
\g__regex_case_int=\count94
\l__regex_case_max_group_int=\count95
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count96
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count97
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count98
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count99
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count100
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count101
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count102
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count103
\l__regex_last_char_success_int=\count104
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count105
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count106
\l__regex_step_int=\count107
\l__regex_min_thread_int=\count108
\l__regex_max_thread_int=\count109
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count110
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count111
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count112
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count113
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count114
\l__regex_added_begin_int=\count115
\l__regex_added_end_int=\count116
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count117
\c_empty_box=\box12
\l_tmpa_box=\box13
\l_tmpb_box=\box14
\g_tmpa_box=\box15
\g_tmpb_box=\box16
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen21
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen22
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen23
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen24
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen25
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen26
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen27
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen28
\l__box_internal_box=\box17
\l__color_internal_int=\count118
\g__color_model_int=\count119
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box18
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen29
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen30
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen31
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen32
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen33
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen34
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen35
\c_empty_coffin=\box19
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box20
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box21
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box22
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box23
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box24
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box25
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen36
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen37
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen38
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen39
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen40
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen41
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen42
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box26
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box27
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box28
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box29
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen43
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen44
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen45


! LaTeX3 Error: File 'UnicodeData.txt' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.31675   }
           
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

By the way, I installed both programs in single user mode.

Comment: I have seen this error a few times. In one case the unicode-data package simply wasn't installed https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344493/2388., but there are also cases where it is unknown what triggers it.  https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/901.  Install texlive 2022 if you don't get miktex working.

Comment: You should launch `MikTeX Settings`, click on the `formats` tab and select the formats you want to build.